# How to change language of python plotly express modebar?

Tags: python, plotly, locale, plotly-python

I have tried:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL , 'de_DE')
```

and

```
config = {
    'locale': 'de-DE'
}
fig.show(config=config)
```

But the modebar tooltips are still in English
[image]

I saw that [plotly.js has a translated version](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/2217/files) but in plotly.py I could not find it in the code...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the plotly documentation](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#to-include-localization) you need to register new languages.

In your case this means you need to add

```
https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-de-latest.js
```

to your dashboard.

You can do this either by adding

```
app.scripts.append_script({"external_url": "https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-de-latest.js"})
```

or by downloading the .js file and coping it to the assets folder in your dashboards root folder.

See https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources for more information.

Comment: This is when you are using [dash](https://dash.plotly.com/) as webapp framework but not when only using [plotly.py](https://plotly.com/python/) inside another framework (in my case streamlit)